# pub/sub with gproc - what is module?

Tags: erlang

Reading gproc docs, it looks like they `Key` is used to routed the messages to different processes, so I can't figure out how the *pub/sub* example works in the docs, as it seems to be using different keys for registering and sending messages.

In the [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/wiki/Publish-subscribe-with-gproc) docs, they provide the following example of implementing pub/sub:

```
subscribe(Event) ->
    gproc:reg({p, l, {?MODULE, Event}}).

publish(Event, Data) ->
    gproc:send({p, l, {?MODULE, Event}}, {?MODULE, Event, Data}).
```

The `gproc:send` 2nd argument: `{?MODULE, Event, Data}`, wouldn't that make the message different based on which module is sending the event?

So for example if I subscribe to event of type `foo_bar` from module1:

```
pub_sub:subscribe(foo_bar).
```

and then publish an event from module2:

```
pub_sub:publish(foo_bar, {color, "Blue"}).
```

The calls to gproc for the first call would be:

```
gproc:reg({p, l, {module1, foo_bar}}).
```

while for the second:

```
gproc:send({p, l, {module2, foo_bar}}, {module2, foo_bar, {color, "Blue}}).
```

So it seems like the keys are different: `{p, l, {module1, foo_bar}}` and `{p, l, {module2, foo_bar}}`, and *module1* will never receive the message.

Or am I missing something?

P.S.: There is a slightly different syntax [here](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc#use-case-pubsub-patterns), but I still see the same problem:

```
subscribe(EventType) ->
    %% Gproc notation: {p, l, Name} means {(p)roperty, (l)ocal, Name}
    gproc:reg({p, l, {?MODULE, EventType}}).

notify(EventType, Msg) ->
    Key = {?MODULE, EventType},
    gproc:send({p, l, Key}, {self(), Key, Msg}).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The key would be the same, because the `?MODULE` macro always expands to the module it is defined in!

So it would actually be `{p, l, {pub_sub, foo_bar}}` for both calls.

References: [This](http://blog.rusty.io/2009/09/16/g-proc-erlang-global-process-registry/) post was useful in understanding gproc.